# How to calculate median of profits for a particular country

Tags: r, median

Hello folks,
             I am new to R and I am trying to compute median profit for a particular country in a data frame.I tried below one but it doesn't work for me.

```
data("Forbes2000", package = "HSAUR")
median(Forbes2000[,"sales","country"="United States"])
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
median(Forbes2000$sales[Forbes2000$country == "United States"])
```

Though it's hard to be certain without knowing what your data frame looks like. If you want to get a data.frame with the median of every country instead of just one, you could do:

```
library(plyr)
ddply(Forbes2000, "country", function(d) median(d$sales))
```

(You would have to install the [plyr](http://plyr.had.co.nz/) package first, for example by doing `install.packages("plyr")`).

Comment: Note: OP might need to install the `plyr` package to use `ddply`.

Comment: How about if I need median for multiple countries?

Comment: @Vutukuri: Did you see my `ddply` answer?

Answer (score 2):

David already answered your initial question and showed you one way to find the median for multiple countries.  Here is another way:

You can `split` the `data.frame` by country to create a `list` of `data.frame`s
for each country

```
L <- split(Forbes2000, Forbes2000$country)
```

Then, you can apply a function to each component of the `list` with either
`lapply` or `sapply`.  (`sapply` simplifies the result to an array, whereas
`lapply` returns a `list`)

```
sapply(L, function(x) {
    median(x$sales)
})
```

or, in one line

```
sapply(split(Forbes2000, Forbes2000$country), function(x) median(x$sales))
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to calculate median values for a metric in column 11 by US state in dataframe 'outcome3' using:

`tapply(outcome3[,11], outcome3$State, median)`