# How to find average of a col1 grouping by col2

Tags: r, group-by, average, mean

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Idiomatic R code for partitioning a vector by an index and performing an operation on that partition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10748253/idiomatic-r-code-for-partitioning-a-vector-by-an-index-and-performing-an-operati)
>   [How to calculate median of profits for a particular country](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12185319/how-to-calculate-median-of-profits-for-a-particular-country)

I am trying to find average of a column by using another column in R.It's so easy to do it in SQL but not able to find proper functions and implement them.Here is some sample data as below.

```
data("Forbes2000", package = "HSAUR")
head(Forbes2000)

##    rank                name        country             category  sales profits  assets marketvalue
## 1    1           Citigroup  United States              Banking  94.71   17.85 1264.03      255.30
## 2    2    General Electric  United States        Conglomerates 134.19   15.59  626.93      328.54
## 3    3 American Intl Group  United States            Insurance  76.66    6.46  647.66      194.87
## 4    4          ExxonMobil  United States Oil & gas operations 222.88   20.96  166.99      277.02
## 5    5                  BP United Kingdom Oil & gas operations 232.57   10.27  177.57      173.54
## 6    6     Bank of America  United States              Banking  49.01   10.81  736.45      117.55
```

Comment: THere are many ways of doing this. look at the `plyr`, `data.table`, `sqldf` packages (to mention a few), and in base R the functions  `aggregate`, `tapply` and `ave`. There are a multitude of related question on SO.

Comment: You should try searching again, this question has been answered 100s of times on SO. Check out the `plyr`, `data.table` tags as well as the `ddply` function in particular, or `aggregate`, or `ave`, or any other number of functions. [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10748253/idiomatic-r-code-for-partitioning-a-vector-by-an-index-and-performing-an-operati/10748470#10748470O) provides a reasonably extensive list of most of your options and some relative timings for each.

Comment: Part of the negativity toword this question is probably due to the impossibility of importing that file with the usual read.* function in R. You can do it with `read.fwf` in the utils package but it's a pain. Learn to post the output of `dput()` applied to the head of your dataframe.

Comment: @Vutukuri, Less than an hour before this question was asked, I edited 2 of your questions to make them reproducible by adding `data("Forbes2000", package = "HSAUR")` ...

Comment: Also, one of [the answers](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12188188/967840) I gave would work for this if you substitute `mean` for `median`

Comment: Might help to tell us which 2 columns you had in mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a data.frame named `dat` that looked like:

```
     rank              name  country       category  sales profits assets marketvalue
21     21   DaimlerChrysler Germany    Consumer_dur 157.13    5.12 195.58       47.43
```

Try (untested d/t the numerous spaces in the text preventing read.table from making sense of it):

```
aggregate(dat[ , c("sales", "profits", "assets", "marketvalue")],   # cols to aggregate
          dat["country"],                                           # group column
          FUN=mean)                          # aggregation function
```